# How do I translate this Java interface & inheritence structure to Golang?

Tags: java, inheritance, go

Is it possible to rewrite this Java structure that uses interfaces and inheritance into an idiomatic Golang way?

It's not super complicated Java code, but it shows the strength of class inheritance, but I would like to try and achieve the same result in Go somehow

The Java Code:

First there is a class Interface.

```java
public interface WebEntry {
    String perform(ConnectionData connectionData, SessionData sessionData) throws Exception;
}
```

Somewhere there is a list of web entries `WebEntry`:

```java
List<WebEntry> webEntries = new ArrayList<>();
webEntries.add( new SavePasswordWebEntry() );
```

An abstract class `UserLoggedInWebEntry` that implements a `WebEntry`

```java
public abstract class UserLoggedInWebEntry implements WebEntry {

    @Override
    public String perform(ConnectionData connectionData, SessionData sessionData) throws Exception {

        // THIS IS THE LOGIC I DO NOT WANT TO DUPLICATE, HENCE ITS USING CLASS INHERITANCE
        ...

        return userPerform(User user);

    }

    protected abstract String userPerform(User user) throws Exception;

}
```

By using class inheritance, we can create a `UserLoggedInWebEntry` which still behaves as a `WebEntry` but we don't need to duplicate the `...` logic each time we want a "user logged in web entry" instance:

```java
public class SavePasswordWebEntry extends UserLoggedInWebEntry {

    @Override
    protected String userPerform(User user) throws Exception {
       ...
    }

}
```

So the whole point is that, since its using class inheritance, a developer only needs to implement `String userPerform(User user)` without duplicating the logic of `...` in `UserLoggedInWebEntry`.

Is this even possible to achieve in Golang? If so, how would it look like?

Comment: Recreate what? A mess like any Java code? Yes, you can do stupid things in Go too. What is the actual question about Go code?

Comment: Like I said in the question:

> However, by creating an abstract class UserLoggedInWebEntry, a developer can easily create web entries that only implements a method that has the signature protected String userPerform(User user) without duplicating the ... logic in UserLoggedInWebEntry.perform(...).

By using the class inheritance here, the develop doesn't need to duplicate the "..." logic that is taken place in `UserLoggedInWebEntry `

Comment: That's my question. How do I achieve the same thing in Golang? Is this even possible? If so how

Comment: "Just learn Go" - that's.. what I am trying.. to do by asking.. this question on Stackoveflow. If I knew Go properly and how to achieve the same thing, I wouldn't be asking it here.

Comment: The main advice was: Stop recreating Java patterns in Go. You will hurt yourself. Leave that behind. You cannot do it and you won't succeed. Do not ask "How do I do pattern X of Java in Go." Sorry if I was not clear on that.

Comment: You saying stop recreating Java patterns in Go, when I wrote "Is it possible to rewrite this Java structure that uses interfaces and inheritance into an idiomatic Golang way?" - I literally asked how to rewrite it in a go idiomatic way. Note the word "idiomatic", as in how to solve it in the Go way. But whatever, I have figured it out and posted my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve the same thing by myself, even though I enjoyed the "Just learn Go" answers I got.

It's solved by creating a wrapper function `userLoggedInWebEntry` that takes in a `WebEntryUserLoggedIn` function signature, but returns a `WebEntry` function signature.

It achieves the same thing as the Java inheritance code above, by letting the developer only implement a `func( user User ) string` and the logic in `userLoggedInWebEntry` is not duplicated

https://play.golang.org/p/adrk46YFIl8

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ConnectionData string
type SessionData string
type User string

type WebEntry func(connectionData ConnectionData, sessionData SessionData) string
type WebEntryUserLoggedIn func( user User ) string

func main() {
    var webentries []WebEntry
    webentries = append( webentries, userLoggedInWebEntry(SavePasswordWebEntry) )

    // Test the invocation
    fmt.Println( webentries[0]("ConnectionData", "SessionData") )
}


func userLoggedInWebEntry( webEntry WebEntryUserLoggedIn ) WebEntry {

    return func(connectionData ConnectionData, sessionData SessionData) string {
        // // THIS IS THE LOGIC I DO NOT WANT TO DUPLICATE, HENCE ITS USING CLASS INHERITANCE
        var user User = "John"
        return webEntry( user )
    } 

}


func SavePasswordWebEntry( user User ) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("user is %s", user )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this?

```
type WebEntry interface {
    Perform() string
}

type SomeWebEntry struct {
}

func (_ *SomeWebEntry) Perform() string {
    return "SomeWebEntry"
}

type OtherWebEntry struct {
    SomeWebEntry
}

func (this *OtherWebEntry) OtherPerform() string {
    return this.Perform() + "OtherWebEntry"
}

func main() {
    webEntries := []WebEntry{&SomeWebEntry{},&OtherWebEntry{}}
    for _, v := range webEntries {
        fmt.Println(v.Perform())
    }
    fmt.Println("-")
    fmt.Println(webEntries[1].(*OtherWebEntry).OtherPerform())
}
```

You can use a feature called [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html?#embedding).

Answer (score -1):

Here you look.I don't know if I understand it correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ConnectionData struct{}
type SessionData struct{}

type WebEntry interface {
    Perform(c ConnectionData, s SessionData) (string, error)
}

type UserLoggedInWebEntry struct {
}

func (u *UserLoggedInWebEntry) Perform(c ConnectionData, s SessionData) (string, error) {
    return u.UserPerform(c, s)
}

func (u *UserLoggedInWebEntry) UserPerform(c ConnectionData, s SessionData) (string, error) {
    return "UserLoggedInWebEntry UserPerform", nil
}

type SavePasswordWebEntry struct {
    UserLoggedInWebEntry
}

func (sp *SavePasswordWebEntry) Perform(c ConnectionData, s SessionData) (string, error) {
    return "SavePasswordWebEntry Perform", nil
}

func main() {
    webEntries := make([]WebEntry,0)
    webEntries = append(webEntries, new(SavePasswordWebEntry))
    for _, we := range webEntries {
        fmt.Println(we.Perform(ConnectionData{},SessionData{}))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/G6bZZXrD-r2)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect as "SavePasswordWebEntry" should take in a "User" - notice how the argument signature changed. In the above solution, all functions take in "ConnectionData" and "SessionData".